# Swift - Retrieving Image from Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, ios8, xcode7

I've searched over the internet (mostly here) about my issue and I've tried them but I still can't get this to work. I'm trying to retrieve the image from the core data and then display it on a table view. So basically, a table view with a thumbnail image along with a name and a switch. I have the following swift files below. Can anyone lead me what to do? Aside from the image retrieving, I'm planning to add a switch that when turned on/off it asks for a password so that it can be switched on/off. How can I start this? Hoping for your kind responses. Thank you!

I have this snippet of code for saving a record including an image to core data.

```
let mOC =
(UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
    as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

@IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var status: UILabel!

@IBAction func saveRecord(sender: AnyObject) {
    let entityDescription =
    NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Faculty",
        inManagedObjectContext: mOC)

    let faculty = Faculty(entity: entityDescription!,
        insertIntoManagedObjectContext: mOC)

    faculty.firstname = firstName.text
    faculty.lastname = lastName.text

    let pickedImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image!, 1.0)

    faculty.image = pickedImage

    do {
        try mOC.save()
        firstName.text = ""
        lastName.text = ""

        status.text = "New record saved."
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("load", object: nil)
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    } catch {
        status.text = "Record not saved."
    }

}

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
var newMedia : Bool?
@IBAction func choosePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum) {
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType =
                UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true,
                completion: nil)
            newMedia = false

    }

}
```

This is the TableViewController which displays the records on the table view and supposedly with the image, the one I'm trying to figure out.

```
let managedObjectContext =
(UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
    as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

var fetchedLastName = [String]()
var fetchedFirstName = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reloadData:",name:"load", object: nil)

    let entityDescription =
    NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Faculty",
        inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    let request = NSFetchRequest()
    request.entity = entityDescription

    do{
        let objects = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request)

        let results = objects

        if results.count > 0 {
            for var i = 0; i < results.count; i += 1{
                let match = results[i] as! NSManagedObject

                fetchedLastName.append((match.valueForKey("lastname") as? String)!)
                fetchedFirstName.append((match.valueForKey("firstname") as? String)!)

            }
        } else {

        }
    }
    catch{}
}

func reloadData(notification: NSNotification){
    fetchedLastName.removeAll()
    fetchedFirstName.removeAll()

    let entityDescription =
    NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Faculty",
        inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    let request = NSFetchRequest()
    request.entity = entityDescription

    do{
        let objects = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request)

        let results = objects

        if results.count > 0 {
            for var i = 0; i < results.count; i += 1{
                let match = results[i] as! NSManagedObject

                fetchedLastName.append((match.valueForKey("lastname") as? String)!)
                fetchedFirstName.append((match.valueForKey("firstname") as? String)!)
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
    catch{}

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Am I right to think that it is somewhere here that I should write the code to retrieve the image from the core data and display it on the table view?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TEACH", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TEACHTableViewCell

    let row = indexPath.row

    cell.facultyName.text = fetchedLastName[row] + ", " + fetchedFirstName[row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Please only provide relevant code, i.e. the part where you access CoreData

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to save an image?  I see no code where you would do this.  To save an image, you would simply convert to data and then set a value on the ManagedObject

Comment: What's the problem exactly?, where are you planning to show that image?

Comment: @milesper I edited the post. I think I've figured out how to save the image, its the retrieving which I can't do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok here is the fixed code:

TeachTableViewController:

```
//
//  TEACHTableViewController.swift
//  TEACH
//
//  Created by ICST340.N1 on 9/29/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 IyoTugs. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

class TEACHTableViewController: UITableViewController {
let managedObjectContext =
(UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
    as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

var fetchedLastName = [String]()
var fetchedFirstName = [String]()
var fetchedImage = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reloadData:",name:"load", object: nil)

    let entityDescription =
    NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Faculty",
        inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    let request = NSFetchRequest()
    request.entity = entityDescription

    do{
        let objects = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request)

        let results = objects

        if results.count > 0 {
            for var i = 0; i < results.count; i += 1{
                let match = results[i] as! NSManagedObject

                fetchedLastName.append((match.valueForKey("lastname") as? String)!)
                fetchedFirstName.append((match.valueForKey("firstname") as? String)!)
                //added this is convert the image
                let image = match.valueForKey("image") as! NSData
                fetchedImage.append(UIImage(data: image)!)

            }
        } else {

        }
    }
    catch{}
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncommented this
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the          navigation bar for this view controller.
    //        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

func reloadData(notification: NSNotification){
    fetchedLastName.removeAll()
    fetchedFirstName.removeAll()
    //Added this to remove all images
    fetchedImage.removeAll()

    let entityDescription =
    NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Faculty",
        inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    let request = NSFetchRequest()
    request.entity = entityDescription

    do{
        let objects = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request)

        let results = objects

        if results.count > 0 {
            for var i = 0; i < results.count; i += 1{
                let match = results[i] as! NSManagedObject

                fetchedLastName.append((match.valueForKey("lastname") as? String)!)
                fetchedFirstName.append((match.valueForKey("firstname") as? String)!)
                //added this is convert the image
                let image = match.valueForKey("image") as! NSData
                fetchedImage.append(UIImage(data: image)!)

            }
        } else {

        }
    }
    catch{}

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return fetchedLastName.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TEACH", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TEACHTableViewCell

    let row = indexPath.row

    print(fetchedFirstName)

    cell.facultyName.text = fetchedLastName[row] + ", " + fetchedFirstName[row]
    cell.facultyImage.image = fetchedImage[row]

    return cell
}

}
```

I marked each spot that I fixed, but there were only four spots. Two of them had to do with taking the NSData and turning it into an Image(in viewDidLoad and reloadData, same spots). One of them add to do with commenting out the line that made the right navbar button an edit button. And the last one fetchedImage.removeAll()  on the top of reloadData to take out all of the images.

Comment: I already had it working but thanks for this :) I wasn't able to think of that approach but hey nice :) New question though, I'm planning to add a search function in the tableview so that if I have a lot of rows, I can easily look for the name I'm looking for. Any idea how I can begin? I know I need to use the search bar but I don't know how to begin in code.

Comment: After all my work I put in this you just mark yours as correct?!?!

Comment: I know how to do that, but I am not going to help, if I don't even get my correct answer being marked as correct.

Comment: Thanks it helps out a lot, do you want to make a new post with this question and I will right a full answer there?

Comment: I have it here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994181/adding-a-searchbar-on-tableview

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what Faculty() contains but, you need to save the image as NSData to CoreData, then when you want to get the image from CoreData you take the NSData and convert it to an image like so:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "BackgroundSky")
//Change named: "" to your image
let imageAsNSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1.0)
```

And then save it to CoreData as NSData, then when you get that back from CoreData, this is how you turn it into an image:

```
let image = UIImage(data: imageAsNSData!)
//Change data: to the NSData
```

And that is how change and image back and forth from UIImage to NSData.

Comment: Just like a normal image @Alexsanity, when you do let image = UIImage(data: imageAsNSData!), you add it to your tableViewCell like faculty.image = image, off course you need to add a property called image and of type UIImage in your tableViewCell Class,

Comment: My Faculty entity contains 3 attributes: firstname (String), lastname (String), image (Binary Data). How do I display it on the table view? 

I did something like
    cell.facultyImage.image = UIImage(withData: Faculty.image)
but I was getting an error saying that Faculty.Type does not have a member image.

Comment: What you did to do is have "My Faculty" contain a UIImage not Binary Data, then pass your UIImage that you created from NSData to "My Faculty". Make sure your custom cell has a UIImage and is connected to a UIImage property in "My Faculty",

Comment: Hmm. I'll have to test it out once I'm in front of a mac. How do I fetch the image data from core data?

Comment: Like any other property just cast it to NSData

Comment: Is it supposed to follow something like this?

cell.facultyName.text = fetchedLastName[row] + ", " + fetchedFirstName[row] only an example.

Comment: I'm trying this cell.facultyImage.image = UIImage(withData: Faculty.image?) but I get the error Faculty.Type does not have a member named 'image' when I have an image attribute in the Faculty entity.

Comment: Did you make a variable in faculty(table view cell) that Is called image and of type UIImage?

Comment: I have  '@IBOutlet weak var facultyName: UILabel!
    '@IBOutlet weak var facultyImage: UIImageView!

Comment: This is in my ViewController.swift 
let pickedImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image!, 1.0)
faculty.image = pickedImage

How do I use UIImage(withData: pickedImage) if I'm going to use it on a separate ViewController (TableViewController)

Comment: Different question. Might be able to work around this. If I have this... 
if results.count > 0 {
                for var i = 0; i < results.count; i += 1{
                    let match = results[i] as! NSManagedObject
                    
                    fetchedLastName.append((match.valueForKey("lastname") as? String)!)
                    fetchedFirstName.append((match.valueForKey("firstname") as? String)!)


How do I do the same to fetch the image from the core data?

Comment: faculty.image = UIImage(withData: pickedImage)

Comment: Will that work? My pickedImage is in a different swift file, and will that automatically work for all rows in the tableview (object 1 in core data in row 1, object 2 in row 2, object 3 in row 3 and so on and so forth)?

Comment: Won't it say like pickedImage is not initialized or something since its on a different file.

Comment: Yes...Its should at least.

Comment: Hmm I'll have to test it out when I'm on a mac again. If in case it works, will it be able to populate the table view's rows with the right image (object 1 fro m core data in row 1, object 2 in row 2, etc) ?

Comment: It should, but you will have to test it because I do not have all the code.

Comment: I have it here if you want to check. Haven't had the chance to use a mac yet. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5-_n15qdwJpOFlScE5YMG5CNGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: faculty.image = UIImage(withData: pickedImage) doesn't work. It says pickedImage is not initialized.

Comment: Help please? I can't move forward :/

Answer (score 0):

Solved by doing so:

```
var fetchedImage = [NSData]()

fetchedImage.append((match.valueForKey("image") as? NSData)!)
```

and

```
cell.facultyImage.image = fetchedImage[row]
```